# Full screen div sliding from up in vue2JS

Tags: css, animation, vue.js, vuejs2, transition

I'm trying to create a 100% width and 100vh height div which would slide from out of the screen from above to down of page. At the 70% of animation I would like to make it at the bottom then at 90% move it 30px up and on 100% make it at the bottom again so it would look like it slide from up then bounce at the bottom.

I want this happen after clicking some DOM element in a grand grandchild so basically, I'll use eventBus and my "sliding div" will be in root component (`app.vue`) and in the child I'll emit:

```
showObserved() {
     eventBus.$emit('showObserved');
}
```

here I'm emitting my custom event and then I'm watching this event in root component and changing boolean variable:

```
eventBus.$on('showObserved', async() => {
    this.showObserved = true;
});
eventBus.$on('hideObserved', async() => {
    this.showObserved = false;
});
```

and basing on this boolean I'm displaying my sliding div using `v-if` directive:

```
<transition name="slide-up" mode="out-in">
    <observed-offer v-if="showObserved"></observed-offer>
</transition>
```

and here finally I use `transition` vue built-in component in order to make it sliding and this are my styles which should make effect that I explained in first parahraph:

```
/* slide from up to down */
.slide-up-leave-active {
    animation: slide-out-up .4s linear;
}

.slide-up-enter-active {
    animation: slide-in-up .4s linear forwards;
}

.slide-up-in-leave-active {
    animation: slide-out-up .4s linear;
}

.slide-up-leave {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}

@keyframes slide-out-up {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    70% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    90% {
        transform: translateY(10%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
@keyframes slide-in-up {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
    70% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    90% {
        transform: translateY(10%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

and this are style's of my sliding div:

```
.observed {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 999999999;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}
```

But this doesn't work behavior is that it instantly makes entire page white and slide only content of div. I'm pretty sure that I just made wrong CSS styles I tried various other styles and it didn't work. Also maybe it has also something to do with `height: 100vh`.

---

I add [demo repository](https://bitbucket.org/dopeCode/vueslidevertical/src/master/). In this demo sliding in is almost working but slide out doesn't work at all. Installation of this project is simple just clone it then `cd path/to/project` then `npm install && npm run dev` or something similiar depending on OS.

In demo it's also not hovering entire page but it leave space for button as you'll see if you clone it.

---

Well actually I handle to fix transitions in demo repo now the only issue is that it doesn't veil/cover entire page but it leave space for root content. Pull repo again to see that.

Comment: could you share your code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) in order to test it and see the problem

Comment: I don't think that's possible due to importing things like eventBus and `<template>,<script>` syntax. I can create demo repository tho.

Comment: you could easily share it with codesandbox or use a git repo

Comment: I'll update question in 20 minutes and I'll add demo repo.

Comment: Done. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was that I was using bad transition styles and that I didn't have fixed position with top: 0 left: 0 on my panel component. After fixing that it's working correctly as you can inspect in demo repository.

Sorry for wasting time for issue that I fixed myself but it was much harder to troubleshoot in origin big project. When I created this demo repo it became so easy.